# numpy-based spatial reduction

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, rasterio

I'm looking for a flexible fast method for computing a custom reduction on an np.array using a square non-overlapping window. e.g.,

```
array([[4, 7, 2, 0],
       [4, 9, 4, 2],
       [2, 8, 8, 8],
       [6, 3, 5, 8]])
```

let's say I want the `np.max`, (on a 2x2 window in this case) I'd like to get:

```
array([[9, 4],
       [8, 8]])
```

I've built a slow function using for loops, but ultimately I need to apply this to large raster arrays.

[scipy.ndimage.generic_filter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.generic_filter.html#scipy.ndimage.generic_filter) is close, but this uses sliding windows (with overlap), giving a result with the same dimensions (no reduction).

[numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html) combined with a reducing function doesn't seem to handle relationships between rows (i.e., 2D spatial awareness).

[rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/resampling.html) has some nice resampling methods built on GDAL, but these don't allow for custom reductions.

[skimage.transform.downscale_local_mean](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html?highlight=transform#skimage.transform.downscale_local_mean) does not support custom functions on the blocks.

I'm sure there's something out there for custom [spatial anti-aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing), but I can't seem to find a solution and am feeling dumb.

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the max (or other function supporting axis), you can just reshape the array:

```
a.reshape(a.shape[0]//2, 2, a.shape[1]//2, 2).max(axis=(1,3))
```

In general, you can reshape, swap the axis, flatten the 2x2 into a new axis `4`, then work on that axis.

Comment: That works! thanks for the quick response. I guess you're 'in general' statement is meant to apply to functions without an axis kwarg. For those as slow as me, the answer code is stacking each of the spatial blocks/windows into axis 1 and 3..